# How to get Facebook friends list using FBSDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios9, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to fetch the list of friends from facebook in my app. I'm able to get the `total_friends` correctly, but the list of friends is not coming in the result.

My current code that is not working:

**CODE:**

```
NSMutableString *facebookRequest = [NSMutableString new];
[facebookRequest appendString:@"/me/friends"];
[facebookRequest appendString:@"?limit=100"];

NSDictionary *friendParams = @{@"fields" : @"name"};



FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                                               parameters:friendParams
                                                               HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    //my code here
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 661;
    };
}
```

I'm using Xcode 7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used similar methods but my code is in swift. Your friends list are their but you don't get the name for that u have to create an array. And put all the result of your friends into that array. and display it wherever you want to show.

Here is the code for Facebook friends in swift:

```
  let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: ["fields": "id,name,picture"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler( { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {

                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            else
            {                 
               let friends = result.valueForKey("data") as! NSArray
                var count = 1
                if let array = friends as? [NSDictionary] {
                    for friend : NSDictionary in array {
                        let name = friend.valueForKey("name") as! String
                        frindsFromGlobal.append(name)
                        count++
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: The above code works only with the condition as provided by @iPrabu and with a small correction instead of "let friends = result.valueForKey("data") as! NSArray" you should just use "let friends = result.valueForKey("data")". Because if the data is going to be nil unwrapping it will cause trouble.

Answer (score 3):

From v2.0 `/me/friends` will only return the friends who are using your app.

So in your case the app that you have created in developer.facebook.com is not authorised or used by any of your friends

Also you must request the `user_friends` permission from each user

Comment: a) Is there any other way to get the complete list? If NO, then its ok I will manage with whatever list of friends is returned by facebook.
b) What do I have to do to request  permission for `user_friends`? FYI, I'm not getting any error because of permission not granted.